# 'Zeus_Private_Limited.Form4' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#

```
namespace Zeus_Private_Limited
{

    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {

        public Form4(string access)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //get the accessibility value to label
            label9.Text = access;
        }

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"E:\\HND\\Semester 2\\Programming With C#\\Assignment\\System\\Zeus Private Limited\\Zeus Private Limited\\ZeusDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True");

        //Employee class is the sub class of Form4 class
        public class Employee : Form4
        {
            //All Employees can Register and Search products
            private void Register_Product()
            {

                if (textBox1.Text != "" || textBox2.Text != "" || textBox3.Text != "" || textBox4.Text != "" || textBox5.Text != "")
                {
                    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Add one product to products list?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
```

Comment: At a guess (though it's hard to tell with the incomplete code posted) you need to have a parameterless constructor for `Form4` for your `Employee` class.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask a question, but in order to call your Form, you need something like this:

```
var frm = Zeus_Private_Limited.Form4("ReadOnly");
frm.Show();
```

This is because you construct your Form requiring "access" as a String Parameter:

```
public Form4(string access)
```

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, I'm new to the forum. Anyway thankx for the help. It solves my problem